# Get Table Properties out of Hive using Java API

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hive, metastore

I'm trying to get table properties like table db, name, owner, and hdfs location out of the hive metastore using the metastore client in java. I think I can get the table databases and names okay, but I can't figure out how to grab things like owner and hdfs location. Is it possible? I've been searching the doc and internet for a couple hours now and no dice.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I want to use the hive metastore client however, not run describes. I found what I was looking for, I missed the Table api entirely. Derp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be something like that:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Table table=..........;
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.StorageDescriptor sd=table.getSd();
String loc=sd.getLocation();
String own=sd.getOwner();
```

https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/Table.html
https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/StorageDescriptor.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is a partitioned table, you can do a :

describe formatted table partition(partition_name=partition_value).

It will display the underlying  hdfs path and the owner of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command on my virtualbox having Cloudera CDH 5.1.0

$ hive -e "describe extended ***tablename***"

The output of this command provides information in addition to tablename, dbname, owner, createtime, location. You can also refer the following CWIKI link for more details

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Describe