# Hive Metastore - How to use Client API to get Create Table String?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, metastore

I am able to use the HiveMetaStoreClient `getTable` function. However, this does not have all the information I need (e.g. parameters for SerDe function during table creation).

Is there a way for me to use the Hive Metastore to see the create table call as I would if I called `show create table test` in the hive shell?

Comment: It **does** have all the information you need, but you must rummage through the JavaDoc to find it > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880050/get-table-properties-out-of-hive-using-java-api

Comment: Thanks, I did not look carefully enough. I ended up finding the information in the StorageDescriptor object.