# Does Apache Hive have an equivalent to PostgreSQL's pg_dump?

Tags: hive

I have a bunch of databases in Apache Hive. I want to output their structure - table names, column names, keys, relationships, etc.  An equivalent of PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` would be perfect. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what kind of "keys" and "relationships" do you expect to find in Hive?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I just got access to a bunch data and started playing around with Hive. I thought it was structured like SQL...This is why I'm looking for a high-level description of the data and it's structure :)

Comment: If you want to view only the table structure then best way to connect to database linked to your hive (mysql or derby) and view the schema. You can find these details in hive-site.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I know three ways to do that kind of stuff. None of which is fun.

**A.** Use some custom scripting and Beeline (or Hive CLI) to reverse engineer all the tables and views

- run a `show databases` query
- parse the result, iterate on `show tables in **`
- parse the result, iterate on `show CREATE TABLE **.**`
- ...and `show partitions **.**` and `show indexes **.**` *(but you have to rebuild the ALTER TABLE / CREATE INDEX commands by yourself)*
- if you have an authorization policy, also run `show principals` and iterate on `show grant **` *(but you have to rebuild the CREATE ROLE and GRANT commands by yourself)*

**B.** Develop your custom Java program to connect to the MetaStore service, scan the databases, scan the tables/views, scan the partitions, scan the `StorageDescriptor`, scan the columns, scan everything and its dog ... to get what you really want. Good luck. [Some pointers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880050/get-table-properties-out-of-hive-using-java-api).

**C.** Connect straight to the MetaStore database back-end (Derby, MySQL, Postgres...) then try to understand where the stuff you want is located and *SELECT* whatever you need

Comment: Note that with tables using an AVRO SerDe, or linked to an HBase back-end, you may not see any column; the full schema will be described in the TBLPROPERTIES (which may simply point to an URL).