# How to list HDFS location of all the partitions in a hive table?

Tags: hive

Using the command:

```
describe formatted my_table partition my_partition
```

we are able to list the metadata including hdfs location of the partition `my_partition` in `my_table`. But how can we get an output with 2 columns:

```
Partition | Location
```

which would list all the partitions in `my_table` and their hdfs locations?

Comment: You can't. Commands like `show` or `describe` that display *metadata* are not expected to be used as sources of *data*, that can be then manipulated with SQL.

Comment: But you can use the Java API to access the Hive Metastore, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880050/get-table-properties-out-of-hive-using-java-api >> each `Partition` has its own `StorageDescriptor`; note that there is no `Table` method to access its own `Partition` descriptors, you must get back to `HiveMetastoreClient`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query the metastore.

#### Demo

**Hive**

```
create table mytable (i int) partitioned by (dt date,type varchar(10))
;

alter table mytable add 
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-10',type='A')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-11',type='A')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-12',type='A')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-10',type='B')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-11',type='B')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-12',type='B')
;
```

**Metastore** (MySQL)

```
select  p.part_name
       ,s.location

from            metastore.DBS           as d
        
        join    metastore.TBLS          as t
        
        on      t.db_id         =
                d.db_id
                
        join    metastore.PARTITIONS    as p
        
        on      p.tbl_id        =
                t.tbl_id
                
        join    metastore.SDS           as s
        
        on      s.sd_id         =
                p.sd_id
                
where   d.name     = 'default'
    and t.tbl_name = 'mytable'
;
```

---

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      part_name       |                                     location                                     |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dt=2017-06-10/type=A | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-10/type=A |
| dt=2017-06-11/type=A | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-11/type=A |
| dt=2017-06-12/type=A | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-12/type=A |
| dt=2017-06-10/type=B | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-10/type=B |
| dt=2017-06-11/type=B | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-11/type=B |
| dt=2017-06-12/type=B | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-12/type=B |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That's a very naughty trick. By the way, is there any recent documentation -- official or not -- about the Metastore data model? Because sometimes you don't only want to get data from it; sometimes you have to update the bloody thing because your Prod version upgrade just trashed your Prod system... I've been there.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not necessary to get the information in a nice tabular format - and you do not have access to the HMS database, you may want to run the `explain extended`:

```
explain extended select * from default.mytable;
```

and then you can grep out the essential information, the `partition values` and the `location`.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya# hive -e "explain extended select * from default.mytable;" | grep location
OK
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-10/type=A
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-10/type=B
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-11/type=A
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-11/type=B
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-12/type=A
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/dt=2017-06-12/type=B
location hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution from my point of view is to get this info from Hive Metastore via Thrift protocol.
If you write code in python, you can use from [hmsclient](https://pypi.org/project/hmsclient/) library:

Hive cli:

```sql
hive> create table test_table_with_partitions(f1 string, f2 int) partitioned by (dt string);
OK
Time taken: 0.127 seconds

hive> alter table test_table_with_partitions add partition(dt=20210504) partition(dt=20210505);
OK
Time taken: 0.152 seconds
```

Python cli:

```py
>>> from hmsclient import hmsclient
>>> client = hmsclient.HMSClient(host='hive.metastore.location', port=9083)
>>> with client as c:
...    all_partitions = c.get_partitions(db_name='default',
...                                      tbl_name='test_table_with_partitions', 
...                                      max_parts=24 * 365 * 3)
...
>>> print([{'dt': part.values[0], 'location': part.sd.location} for part in all_partitions])
[{'dt': '20210504', 
  'location': 'hdfs://hdfs.master.host:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_table_with_partitions/dt=20210504'}, 
{'dt': '20210505', 
 'location': 'hdfs://hdfs.master.host:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_table_with_partitions/dt=20210505'}]
```

If you have Airflow installed together with `apache.hive` extra, you create `hmsclient`
using data from Airflow Connections quite easy:

```py
hive_hook = HiveMetastoreHook()
with hive_hook.metastore as hive_client:
    ... your code goes here ...
```