# Athena partition locations

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

I can view all the partitions on my table using

```
show partitions my_table
```

and I can see the location of a partition by using

```
describe formatted my_table partition (partition_col='value')
```

but I have a lot of partitions, and don't want to have to parse the output of `describe formatted` if it can be avoided.

Is there a way to get all partitions and their locations, in a single query?

Comment: this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505554/how-to-list-hdfs-location-of-all-the-partitions-in-a-hive-table assuming you can/have access to the metastore.

Comment: Unfortunately on Athena there's no way to access the metastore

Comment: Did you try `select distinct $path from my_table`? Presto's Hive connector exposes hidden `$path` column which is.. a path to the file containing a row.

Comment: Hi Piotr - `select distinct "$path", partition_col` is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built in or consistent way to get this information.

Assuming you know your partition column(s), you can get this information with a query like

```
select distinct partition_col, "$path" from my_table
```

Answer (score 5):

The cheapest way to get the locations of the partitions of a table is to use the `GetPartitions` call from the Glue API. It will list all partitions, their values and locations. You can try it out using the AWS CLI tool like this:

```
aws glue get-partitions --region us-somewhere-1 --database-name your_database --table-name the_table
```

Using SQL like `SELECT DISTINCT partition_col, "$path" FROM the_table` could be expensive since Athena unfortunately scans the whole table to produce the output (it could have just looked at the table metadata but that optimization does not seem to exist yet).

Comment: Seems like still, this basic optimization is not supported! Thanks a lot for this answer. I hope I didn't find it a query too late after scanning a huge table :( Another advantage of this, is that the result is easy to parse.

Comment: does it return _all_ partitions? When using `boto3` the results are returned in pagination...

Comment: Assuming that the data is structured in Hive-native way (<key>=<value> for partitions), `select distinct regexp_extract("$path", '.+/') FROM the_table` is a good solution that gives all partitions (in a path) and scans 0 bytes.

Comment: @Tim I don't understand how it would scan zero bytes. As I mention in my answer there is no optimisation for `$path`, your query would scan every single byte in the table. There's such an optimisation in newer versions of Presto, but not Athena.

Comment: If the query cannot use the metadata, it would need to check the presence of files on s3. It's fair to call this a "table scan", but that's a loaded term. Athena would not need to read the files and definitely isn't scanning the file contents / rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Using `boto3` (as of version 1.12.9) the following is returning the complete list:

```py
glue_client = boto3.client("glue")
glue_paginator = glue_client.get_paginator("get_partitions")
pages_iter = glue_paginator.paginate(
    DatabaseName=db_name, TableName=table_name
)
res = []
for page in pages_iter:
    for partition in page["Partitions"]:
        res.append(
            {
                "Values": partition["Values"],
                "Location": partition["StorageDescriptor"]["Location"],
            }
        )
```