# How to use Hive Metastore standalone?

Tags: hcatalog, hive-metastore

I installed and ran the Metastore Server standalone, without installing Hive. However, I cannot find any documentation about the thrift network API for communicating with the server. I need to be able to connect to the Metastore server directly or through HCatalog. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HCatalog Java client in `hive-webhcat-java-client`, which can be used in both `client mode` (which connect to hcatalog thrift server) and `embed mode` (which do all the things internally, connect to mysql directly).

```
    HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
    hiveConf.addResource("/Users/tzp/Documents/env/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml");
    //if you set this param, the client try to connect external hive metastore
    hiveConf.set("metastore.thrift.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083");

    HCatClient client = HCatClient.create(new Configuration(hiveConf));
    List<String> dbNames = client.listDatabaseNamesByPattern("*");
    System.out.println(dbNames);
```

I don't think Hive provide similar client in Python, but there is a third party lib [hmsclient](https://pypi.org/project/hmsclient/), do the same thing.

```
from hmsclient import hmsclient
client = hmsclient.HMSClient(host='localhost', port=9083)
with client as c:
    c.check_for_named_partition('db', 'table', 'date=20180101')
```

> HCatalog is functionally identical to Hive Metastore.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for "Hive Metastore client" and its API (branch 1.x) is available at

- https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html
- https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/package-summary.html

Now, good luck finding a tutorial or just code snippets...

Comment: One free snippet anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880050/get-table-properties-out-of-hive-using-java-api/33896565

Comment: Thank you Samson. At this point, I'm using the thrift api in python to access the Metastore server. I may buzz you again if I had more question. Thank you in the meantime!